# postfix for loop in perl is not working as expected

Tags: perl, syntax

The following line works perfectly

```
for(my $i=0; $i < ($max_size - $curr_size) ; $i++){
    push (@{$_}, 0);
}
```

But this one doesn't.

```
push (@{$_}, 0) for (1 .. ($max_size - $curr_size));
```

It gives me an error message like this:

```
Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at coordReadEasy.pl line 124, <DATA> line 16.
```

Why? how can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The range version of `for` sets `$_` to each element, so in `@{$_}` you’re trying to dereference `$_` as though it were an array reference. These are all equivalent:

```
for my $x (1..10) {
  print "$x\n"
}

for (1..10) {
  print "$_\n"
}

print "$_\n" for (1..10);
```

The easy solution is to create another variable for your array reference:

```
push @{$ref}, 0 for 1 .. $max_size - $curr_size;
```

Comment: Even easier: `@$ref = (0) x ($max_size - $curr_size)` :)

Comment: @friedo Except that overwrites what was in the array from before. You might do `push @$ref, (0) x ($max - $curr)` though.

Comment: I want add: **You can't use different variable in postfix loop, only `$_`**